# How to Edit chrome extension contentscript Source Files Directly in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, content-script

I know that we can edit source directly in chrome,

and we can edit the extension background.js in chrome,

just like: https://www.sitepoint.com/edit-source-files-in-chrome/

but how can I edit the contentscript in chrome devtools?

I have set source->filesystem, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Works for me. But you need to edit in the `Filesystem` panel, not in `Content scripts`.

Comment: oh, I can edit in filesystem too. but it is so strange, background.js can edit directly in background.js.

Answer (score 0):

**ContentScripts Live Edit**

TL;DR: You need WorkSpace, dinamic import and //# sourceURL=

0. Add Extension Folder to **WorkSpace**
1. In **Manifest**

   {"matches":
   ["https://example.com/*"],
   "js": [
   "loader.js"
   ]
   },
2. In **loader.js**

   await import(chrome.runtime.getURL("contentScript.js"));
3. In **End Of contentScript.js**

   //# sourceURL=file:///C:/path/To/Extension/contentScript.js

After that, when you open contentScript from the *Sources* panel or directly from the *Console*, you will be **automatically redirected to the *Filesystem*** and the changes will be saved.

The changes will take effect after the page is reloaded because the contentScript is loaded dynamically. **No need to reboot the extension.**

But there is a bad effect. **The *Network* panel will always have its *Cache Disabled* when opening DevTools (on all pages).**

**ContentCss Live Edit**

Do not add Css in Manifest. Just connect it from contentScript

```
    let href = chrome.runtime.getURL(path);
    let styleSheet = document.createElement("link");
    styleSheet.href = href;
    styleSheet.rel = "stylesheet";
    document.body.append(styleSheet);
```

Сhanges will be displayed immediately